# Base-k representations of polynomials: state of art

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, number-theory

In chapter 4 of Jeffrey Shallit's *A Second Course in Automata Theory* the following problem is formulated as open:

Let $p(n)$ be a polynomial with rational coefficients such that $p(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove or disprove that the language of the base-k representations of all integers in $\{p(n) \mid n \geqslant 0\}$ is context-free if and only if the degree of $p$ is $\leqslant 1$.

What's its status now (as for Oct 2018)? Is it proven? What about some special cases?

Comment: Cross-posted:  https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/41863/5038.   Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.